# Updating form elements with ActionListener from loaded objects

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a form with some checkboxes and spinners. They all have ActionListeners\ChangeListeners assigned to them, so each time you change some element, the program launches a *create()* method, which gathers all the values from the entire form and puts them into object, which can be saved to disc later.

But now I'm trying to make the program to load that object from file and update the interface according to what has been loaded. This is where problems arise. After the program has loaded the object, it tries to update the elements of the form, but just as it changes the first one, ActionListener is triggered and it gathers all the values from the form and overwrites the object that was loaded before.

What would be a good way to solve this problem?

Right now I'm thinking about creating a global variable to "switch off" the *create()* method when I load the object (that is to create a flag that stops action listeners). But I'm not sure if this is a good idea.

Comment: What do you mean by _loading_ objects? [How do I ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Add in a flag that either stops the `ActionListener`'s from performing their tasks or the content from been written to the file.  Set this flag before you load the content

Comment: Loading objects means Serialization in my case by using ObjectInputStream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of flag maybe think of creating an enumeration called FormState to represent states of the form e.g. READ and EDIT. You can toggle the state of the form before and after persisting values.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding a private boolean variable which is changed to false when interface is being updated.